# Cannot create a parse tree from a postfix expression

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, expression

I am trying to create a parse tree from a postfix expression. But it is giving me segmentation error.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include <queue>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

struct my_tree{
    struct my_tree* left;
    char a;
    struct my_tree* right;
};

typedef struct my_tree TREE;


bool is_binary_op(char a){
    if(a == '|' || a == '.') return true;
    else return false;
}

bool is_unary_op(char a){
    if(a == '*') return true;
    else return false;
}

int main() {
    string postfix = "ab|*a.b.";
    stack<TREE*> parse_tree;
    for(unsigned i=0; i<postfix.length(); i++){
        if(is_binary_op(postfix[i])){
            TREE* n;

            TREE* right = parse_tree.top();
            parse_tree.pop();

            TREE* left = parse_tree.top();
            parse_tree.pop();

            n->left = left;
            n->a = postfix[i];
            n->right = right;

            parse_tree.push(n);
        } else if(is_unary_op(postfix[i])){
            TREE* n;

            TREE* left = parse_tree.top();
            parse_tree.pop();

            n->left = left;
            n->a = postfix[i];
            n->right = NULL;

            parse_tree.push(n);
        } else{
            TREE* n;

            n->left = NULL;
            n->a = postfix[i];
            n->right = NULL;
            parse_tree.push(n);
        }
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you used the debugger, what line causes the issue?

Comment: You should remove the 'C' tag since the C language does not support templates.  You are coding in C++ because of the line `stack<TREE*>`.

Comment: this line in the else statement is causing the error

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, I have removed the c tag.

Comment: please help me. I am stuck for hours :'(

Comment: You didn't initialize `n` before assigning `n->left = NULL;`

Comment: i did. in the line just before it, i initialized n.

Comment: TREE* n; here i initialized it

Comment: No, you didn't. You just declared it, but its value is uninitialized.

Comment: what do mean? should i write TREE* n = NULL?

Comment: how do i initialize the n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify all the

```
TREE *n;
```

into

```
TREE *n = new TREE;
```

since all of them seems to be a new node on tree. You need to allocate the actual instance by `operator new`.